# Using a brushless DC motor for generator

Tags: dc-motor, generator

Is it possible to use a brushless DC motor as a generator? If we use the brushless DC motor in the following configuration, the brushless DC motor is used in front wheel of a rover/small car, and the power transmission is done by rear set of wheels, is it possible to recover energy from this configuration? Can we generate electricity from the DC motor in the following configuration?

Comment: What do you mean by power transmission? Is there another motor or engine for the rear wheels?

Comment: yes, the rear wheels are driven either by electric motors, or mechanically, while the front wheels have the brushless DC motors attached to them so as to recover electric energy.

Comment: Discussion of perpetual motion machines is off topic here, in addition to be pointless, of course.

Comment: It isn't even perpetual motion, its just to test the back emf effects of the motor, that can happen when we use the dc motor as generator

Comment: So you want to sense the generated voltage, with no current draw? Then you can just rectify it with 6-pulse diode bridge and smooth it with a low-pass filter to obtain DC voltage.

Comment: Can 6-pulse diode bridge be applied to the motor, when I'm using it as a motor or do I have to use it as a generator, in the scenario described above.

Comment: If you just want to test the BDCM why go to all the touble of mounting it the front wheels of some test vehicle - just connect its shaft to the DC motors that would drive the rear shaft and test it in a controlled manner.

Comment: @user3046538 In fact the body diodes of 3-phase inverter form a rectifier, so it should be possible to measure directly at the driver.

Comment: BLDCM IS an alternator. You need to directly access the coils to use the voltage.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make something out of nothing.

Yes, you can "reclaim" energy from the front wheels while driving the back wheels.  However, the energy that you remove through the front wheels has to come from somewhere, and that somewhere is the back wheels.

The driving energy will have to increase to compensate for the extra load of the power generating wheels.

Electric and hybrid cars already use a similar system to reclaim wasted energy used during braking (which would usually be dissipated as heat), and it's called [Regenerative Braking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_brake)